# nginx root path issue; serving content from wrong folder

Tags: nginx

I can't figure out why nginx is serving some content from /usr/share/nginx/html when I have my config files specifying /var/www/html. This is on Ubuntu 18.04, please give me a clue, thanks.

```
user@Rproxy-ubuntu18:/etc/nginx$ grep "root" -R /etc/nginx/
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:# root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server00.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server00.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server03.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server08.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server07.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server05.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server13.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server11.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server06.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server12.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server04.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server09.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server10.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server02.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server01.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server14.conf: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server00.conf.save: root /var/www/html;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server00.conf.save: root /var/www/html;
```

Main config file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_certificate      '/etc/nginx/ssl/star.crt';
    ssl_certificate_key  '/etc/nginx/ssl/star_example_com.key';

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;


## Define redirects ##
##
    server {
       listen         80;
       return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen       443 ssl default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

        location =/favicon.ico {
            root /var/www/html;
            index  sites.html sites.htm;
        }

        #this section should disable all caching of our static pages
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|htm)$ {
          try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
          expires 1d;
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }

        error_page  404              /sites.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /sites.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /sites.html;
        location = /sites.html {
            root /var/www/html;
        }
    }
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: try `nginx -T | grep "/usr/share/nginx/"` it could be a `alias` not `root`

Comment: OK, don't exactly know how to read that but this is the answer; 

user@Rproxy-ubuntu18:~$ sudo nginx -T | grep "/usr/share/nginx/"
[sudo] password for user:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Your default server does not specify a `root`, so the default value (probably `/usr/share/nginx/html`) will be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. I think the issue is because you have the root inside the location, so by default nginx grabs /usr/share/nginx/

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root /var/www/html;
        index  sites.html sites.htm;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

        #this section should disable all caching of our static pages
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|htm)$ {
          try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
          expires 1d;
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }

        error_page  404              /sites.html;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, in test that behaves as I was expecting.